# Put Hex Into .bin File

Tags: binary, hex

How would you stick a string of hexcode into a .bin  file?  Like this, \x45\x67\x89 for example.  I've seen the long examples where you use bash to strip it then add it to the .bin, but there must be a quicker and simpler way?

Also, I am not too familiar with .bin's, are they a program in themselves?

Comment: `.bin` is a generic extension for files containing binary data, which can really mean anything. Also, what programming language?

Comment: The command line tool `xxd` can convert between hex and binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printf is function wide supported function. C, cpp, php, python, bash...

so classic implementation in C would be:

```
FILE *fp =fopen('binfilename.bin', 'w');
fprintf(fp, "\x45\x67\x89"); fclose(fp);
```

all other languages have similar usage.
you mention bash, and i think there is no simpler way than bash itself:

```
printf "\x45\x67\x89" > binfilename.bin
```

Every file is binary file. If it contains just printable bytes, we call it textual file. If it is generated by compiler and have bytes meaningfull to cpu, not to human, than we say it is 'binary', program. But both textual and binary contains bytes and are binaries. Difference is after, when we/some app interprets it's contents.